# Choosing combo box item with AppleScript doesn't trigger item action

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to use AppleScript to click an item in a select box.

[image: Screenshot of the window]

When clicking the 'More...' item manually with the mouse a standard OSX file chooser dialog opens up, but when I try to do it using AppleScript, the 'More...' item shows up as the chosen item for the select box, but no dialog shows up.

So far I've tried... (element names came from Automator recorder)

```
tell application "System Events"

    click static text 1 of window 1 of application process "DYMO Word Addin"
    -- combo box arrow
    click UI Element 1 of combo box 2 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "DYMO Word Addin"

    set labelsList to (list 1 of scroll area 1 of combo box 2 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "DYMO Word Addin")
    set numLabelsInList to (count text fields of labelsList)
    set theTextField to (text field numLabelsInList of labelsList)

    if numLabelsInList > 1 then

            repeat with z from 1 to (numLabelsInList - 1)
                    key code 125 -- down arrow
            end repeat

    end if

    -- stuff I've tried

    click theTextField
    keystroke return
    key code 36 -- return
    set focused of theTextField to true
    set value of attribute "AXFocused" of theTextField to true
    perform action "AXConfirm" of theTextField

end tell
```

... and now I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch more testing, it turns out that the file dialog only opens when the combo box has focus, and that clicking the combo box arrow button and menu items doesn't actually give it focus.

http://lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2006/Oct/msg00013.html

After trying all of the methods from that thread to give the element focus, even 'click at' didn't work.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40141/when-mousekeys-are-on-how-do-i-click-or-move-the-mouse-using-applescript#answer-40859

That answer recommends [cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) as another way to move and click the mouse, which worked.

So in the end I ended up with

```
click static text 1 of window 1 of application process "DYMO Word Addin"
set labelsComboBox to (combo box 2 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "DYMO Word Addin")

tell labelsComboBox
        set {xPosition, yPosition} to position of labelsComboBox
        set {xSize, ySize} to size
end tell

set {realXPosition, realYPosition} to {(xPosition + (xSize div 2)) as string, (yPosition + (ySize div 2)) as string}

do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick m:" & realXPosition & "," & realYPosition & " dc:" & realXPosition & "," & realYPosition

-- combo box arrow
click UI element 1 of labelsComboBox

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find someone with a similar question and the answer was also cliclick

https://discussions.apple.com/message/17662850#17662850

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.